# Alloy UI time format 24 hours Liferay 6

Tags: java, liferay, alloy-ui

Hi there how to show allow ui date picker for time field using 24 hours format?
I'f I'm using

```
[code]

<%
            Calendar dob = CalendarFactoryUtil.getCalendar();
        dob.setTime(new Date());
        %>

        <aui:input name="schedule_msg" model="<%= Message_Schedule.class %>"
        bean="<%= msch %>" value="<%= now %>" label="Schedule Time"/>



[/code]
```

it shows in am/PM mode...or if using AM/PM mode how to get the value??normally if i want to get value in my Portlet Class just like this
[code]

```
int day = ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "schedule_msgDay");
        int month = ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "schedule_msgMonth");
        int year = ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "schedule_msgYear");
        int hour = ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "schedule_msgHour");
        int min  = ParamUtil.getInteger(request, "schedule_msgMinute");

        try
        {

            msgSchedule.setSchedule_msg(PortalUtil.getDate(month, day, year, hour, min, new PortalException()));
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            msgSchedule.setSchedule_msg(new Date());
        }
```

[/code]
any idea how to get that value??
example in the picture it show 4:54: PM so it means in 24 hours it become 16:54:00 .... Please any help

Thank's

Regards

Danial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aui:input` taglib (which in turn uses the `liferay-ui:input-date` and `liferay-ui:input-time` taglibs) shows the AM/PM select box if the time format for the current locale requires it. In Liferay 6.1.1, have a look at row 36 in `html/taglib/ui/input_time/page.jsp`.

So you should definitely keep the built-in behavior, which shows the AM/PM select box depending on the current locale.

In order to get the date properly in your portlet class, you can draw inspiration from the `EditEventAction` class, which is the Struts action called when you add, update or delete an event in the Calendar portlet. Something like this:

```
int startDateMonth = ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "startDateMonth");
int startDateDay = ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "startDateDay");
int startDateYear = ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "startDateYear");
int startDateHour = ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "startDateHour");
int startDateMinute = ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "startDateMinute");
int startDateAmPm = ParamUtil.getInteger(actionRequest, "startDateAmPm");

if (startDateAmPm == Calendar.PM) {
    startDateHour += 12;
}
```

After that, if you want to get a `Date` object from these values, it's important to decide whether these values represent a date in UTC, in the current user's timezone or whatever. Have a look at the `addEvent` method in `CalEventLocalServiceImpl` class to know how to do it: basically, you have to create a Calendar object with the `CalendarFactoryUtil.getCalendar` method, passing a locale and a timezone, and then you can set the various values.

Answer (score 0):

Liferay UI part is poorly documented, here is the attributes I found, http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/taglibs/liferay-ui/input-time.html, but it never describe how to use these attributes, what are the values of these attributes.

I wasted too much time on googling and experimenting, and I decided to use JQuery datetime pick instead.

Another way is don't use liferay-ui:input-time, just to use your own hours and mins select input.